# Class and component android

Tags: android

I have a activity where in layout I use my own component. 
This is xml my own component:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
    <View 
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@color/patient_view_border"/>
    <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icons_component"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/_andr" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I add this component to layout my activity by add this code to layout my activity:

```
<test.test.IconsComponent
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

now In my component class with extend linearlayout I have a method to change picture this image:

```
public void checkActivity(ActivitiesNames name){
    if(name == ActivitiesNames.TEST_EXTRA){
        testIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.legendaw_andr));
    }
}
```

in my activity i create object of this component and use this method by:

```
        iconsComp = new IconsComponent(getApplicationContext());
        iconsComp.checkActivity(ActivitiesNames.TEST_EXTRA);
```

but i don't see any changes. How can I change icon from my activity in component? 
And second question: how can I send some data from activity to this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes you made are on a new instance you create in code, which does not reflect to your layout. You need to give your view an Id:

```
<test.test.IconsComponent
android:id="@+id/my_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

then instead of creating a new instance:

```
iconsComp = new IconsComponent(getApplicationContext());
```

You need to reference the already inflated one:

```
iconsComp = (IconsComponent) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```